# Confusion moving to ASP.Net from Classic ASP

Tags: c#, asp.net

Probably sounds a bit stupid but I'm getting confused moving from Classic ASP to ASP.net.

After looking at the two different variants of the language, VB or C#, I have decided to go with C#. I was reading another StackOverflow answer that explained moving from VBScript to C# was easier to learn coming from VBScript.

So, I thought I'd hit W3schools to learn some basics on C# but got confused when I was given the options; Web Pages, MVC or Web Forms. Would somebody please explain the differences and which one would suit me best?

I have been coding in classic ASP/VBScript for many years, building all kinds of web application, some big, some small, and I do not want to use any software like Visual Studio, I just want to write code. I currently use Dreamweaver just for coding.

Comment: I wouldn't use w3schools for anything - see http://w3fools.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a move from classic ASP to a .NET web platform, I would suggest going with ASP.NET/MVC.

WebForms are an abstraction that was created to make VB6 programmers comfortable with working on the web and it is a very leaky abstraction. It uses an event model and an idea of `PostBacks` that simply is not part of how the web really works. It has limitations that will not be familiar or make much sense at first (you can only have one form on a page, for example). As such MVC will be much more familiar.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you watch [this video](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/migrating/migrating-from-classic-asp-to-aspnet) by asp.net official developers as well as other relevant videos at the [migrating](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/migrating) section

Here's another good video produced to help programmers to [choose the programming model](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/choosing-the-right-programming-model) (webforms, webpages or mvc, tools, etc)

Although w3schools has several good examples, it has several inconsistencies as well as incorrect information. Good alternatives for w3schools include [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) and [IE Reference API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772384%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (as the name implies, it's aimed to IE, and it's a good reference for when something works in other browsers but not in IE)